# How to check the same data in different table is sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

How to find out the same row is presented in five tables. I need to check the same row is presented in five tables or not, how to check in five tables,here Aduit,Company,Management,Partyconcern,Profile is my five tables,all having same columns and same datatypes,the columns are Name,Company,Loan.can any one sort those out,any ideas for this,struggle for the whole day for this.,

```
    SELECT  Aduit.Name ,
            Aduit.Company ,
            Aduit.Loan ,
            Company.Name ,
            Company.Company ,
            Company.Loan ,
            Management.Name ,
            Management.Company ,
            Management.Loan ,
            Partyconcern.Name ,
            Partyconcern.Name ,
            Partyconcern.Loan ,
            Profile.Name ,
            Profile.Company ,
            Profile.Loan
    FROM    Aduit
            INNER JOIN Company ON ( Aduit.Name = Company.Name
                                    AND Aduit.Company = Company.Company
                                    AND Aduit.Loan = Company.Loan
                                  )
            INNER JOIN Management ON ( Company.Name = Management.Name
                                       AND Company.Company = Management.Company
                                       AND Company.Loan = Management.Loan
                                     )
            INNER JOIN Partyconcern ON Management.Name = Partyconcern.Name
                                       AND Management.Company = Partyconcern.Company
                                       AND Management.Loan = Partyconcern.Loan
            INNER JOIN Profile ON ( Partyconcern.Name = Aduit.Name
                                    AND Partyconcern.Company = Aduit.Company
                                    AND Profile.Loan = Aduit.Loan
                                  )
    WHERE   Aduit.Name = 'sarvan'
            AND Aduit.Company = 'xxx'
            AND Aduit.loan = '15000'
```

Comment: do you mean given one row, check if it exists in all 5 tables, or do you mean look in a table and find all rows that are missing in at least one other table? or do you mean given a row, determine which other table is is included in or not?  perhaps framing your question more clearly will help you with a solution

Comment: take a look at that 
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2779/ways-to-compare-and-find-differences-for-sql-server-tables-and-data/

Comment: `FULL OUTER JOINS`?  What is wrong with the result of the query you are doing?

Comment: @Randy-want to check the single row is presented in five table or not,and also display the table name which is the row is not presented.,

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`INTERSECT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188055.aspx) to check that identical data is in multiple tables.

```
  select name, company, loan from audit
  intersect 
  select name, company, loan from company
  intersect 
  select name, company, loan from management
  intersect
  ....
```

(Your sample isn't working because you're joining `profile` to `audit` using `partyconcern` fields.)

Comment: Simplest and slick way doing it +1 why didnt I think of this :S

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your database isn't [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). You don't need to repeat the same columns in each table, instead link tables using the table primary key. 
For example Name seems to be a property of the Company object, you should not repeat it in the Loan and Audit tables instead link to a CompanyId. You should avoid storing the same data in multiple tables because this allows for corruption (if you change one place and not the other).
For example your tables might look like this:

```
Company(**CompanyId**, Name, Telephone)
Loan(**LoanId**, CompanyId, Amount, LoanDate, Status)
Audit(**AuditId**, LoanId, AuditGrade)
```

where **Primary Keys** are in bold
and then by joining on the primary keys you can find the name of the company being audited like so:

```
Select * From Audit A inner join Loan L on A.LoanId = L.LoanId 
inner join Company C on L.CompanyId=C.CompanyId 
where C.Name = 'sarvan' and L.Amount=15000
```